# /etc/hosts not read by browser?

Tags: linux, dns, linux-mint

I am on Linux Mint 18.1 Serena. Just last week my machine started to behave weirdly. I have several entries in  my /etc/hosts which point to some local websites for development.
For a non apparent reason, last week my browsers stopped being able to resolve those domains, however using curl I do get a valid response. I tried restarting everything but to no luck.

Here is the content of my /etc/hosts and my /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

172.27.0.4 dp-relaunch-coreshop.dp.dev
172.29.0.4 foodexplorer-coreshop.dp.dev


# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed,     try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Is this happening on all browsers? Like Firefox, chromium etc?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that recently updated browsers have issues with local domains that end with `*.dev` try changing them to `*.local` and try again. This solved it for me though I have no idea why

Comment: This was my exact issue. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're on a Unix system, from experience I found that Chrome ignored the systems hosts field, although I was on windows.

Ensure that the user your browser is running on has permissions to read the `/etc/host` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf` files and see if that works.